# For Loop not returning the right sum and minor problem with my code

Tags: python, function, for-loop, sum, equation

```
while True:
n = int(input('Enter a positive number under 10000(0 to quit):'))

if n >= 10000:       print('Number entered is too high, it must be under 10000.') 

elif n == 0:
    print('Closing programm.')
    break

else:
    width_rectangle = 1/n      



    for rectangle in range(n):
        x_left = rectangle * width_rectangle
        x_right = (rectangle * width_rectangle) + width_rectangle   

        y_left = x_left**3 + 1
        y_right = x_right**3 + 1    



        ###My problem is in the following code:

        height = y_left + y_right / 2
        area = height * width_rectangle**`
```

This code works perfectly, except for the part after y_right and y_left. I want to find the total area for n and n= my number of rectangles. So my question is :
How do i only print the sum of the whole area instead of printing every thing that the for loop usually prints? Also, i know my code works but there something wrong with my height and area code because its not giving the right answer and when i do it on paper, it works.

equation that i having trouble with: 
- height = y_left + y_right / 2
and  area = height * width_rectangle

What i've tried so far :
- Adding a second for Loop, didnt give me the right sum
- I tried to put my print outside of the loop because i saw it would give me the 
last iteration of my loop only, it didnt work because my variable was out of range

Lemme know if you require more information.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, order of operations. The line

```
height = y_left + y_right / 2
```

should probably be

```
height = (y_left + y_right) / 2
```

if you're trying to find the average of `y_left` and `y_right`. Division comes before addition, after all.

After this, you're calculating the area, but you're not *doing* anything with it. You need to declare a variable *before* the loop starts, outside of the loop, and use it to store the area at every iteration.

Basically, that means right before the for loop, add the line

```
area_sum = 0
```

and then add a line at the very end of the for loop, right after the one where you calculate area:

```
area_sum += area   # add the area for this rectangle to the sum of areas of all rectangles
```

After which, you can print `area_sum` and it should be what you want. Before, you were getting the out-of-scope error because the variable you declared was locked within the "scope" where it was created - within the for loop. By declaring this variable *outside* the for_loop, instead of inside of it, you should be able to print it outside the for loop as well.

Comment: Thank you so much green, that was very clear and i know exactly what my problem was, thanks for your help!